# Rsync from Windows to Linux, using putty's pagent authentication

Tags: linux, windows, rsync, putty

I want to rsync a directory from windows to Linux.

Linux:

no rsyncd running, commandline rsync shall be called on Linux.

Windows:

I have an ssh-key loaded in pagent.exe
Simple batch-file wanted without installing a program.
cygwin's rsync.exe does not support putty/pagent.

Robocopy is not good because of tremendous amount of files.
How can I rsync from windows to linux in a simple batch-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to install full cygwin, a little directory structure as shown in this batchfile is enough. There's a little helper needed to "marry" cygwin and putty-worlds namely: cygnative.exe

All you need is described in this batch-file:

```
rem This is file: rsync_some_winfiles_to_linux_with_pagent.bat

rem This is what I want:
rem
rem Windows with Putty+Pagent -> rsync -> Linux
rem 
rem pagent.exe is already loaded with my ssh-key
rem This ssh-key shall make the authentication to the remote rsyncd/Linux
rem
rem Environment for this Batch-file:
rem
rem plink.exe for Windows, derived from cygwin
rem download here:
rem    http://it-em.net/joomla/downloads/rsync.zip
rem    with german dokumentation in http://it-em.net/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=49&Itemid=54cms/front_content.php
rem cygnative.exe is needed from plink.exe (putty-suite) 
rem so that plink.exe works together wird rsync.exe
rem download cygnative here:
rem     http://diario.beerensalat.info/2009/08/18/new_cygnative_version_1_2_for_rsync_plink.html
rem
rem Filetree looks like this:
rem + copy_win_inifiles_to_linux_via_rsync_with_pagent.bat
rem + bin/
rem      + rsync.exe
rem      + cygwin1.dll         # needed from rsync.exe
rem      + cygiconv-2.dll      # needed from rsync.exe
rem      + cyggcc_s-1.dll      # needed from rsync.exe
rem      + cygnative.exe       # standalone-program
rem      + plink.exe           # from putty-suite, standalone-program
rem + some-files-dir/          # Here are the file which shall be transferred
rem      + bla.txt
rem      + foo.txt
rem
rem our current working is the same where this bat-file is

set SRC_DIR=./some_files_dir/
set DST_USER=www-data
set DST_SERVER=your-destination-server-with-ssh.example.com
set DST_PORT=23765
set DST_DIR=/var/www/...what-you-like/some_files_dir

bin\rsync.exe -v -d --delete -e="./bin/cygnative.exe ./bin/plink.exe -P %DST_PORT%" %SRC_DIR% %DST_USER%@%DST_SERVER%:%DST_DIR%
```

Comment: The link to `cygnative.exe` is dead. Here are a couple of alternatives that I managed to find: [this gist](https://gist.github.com/silviuvulcan/7609c438f6ab5e51c8d19890e949565f) and [this zip](http://franklinstrube.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/cygnative1.2.zip). I have used the executable contained in the zip, but I cannot vouch for either source. The original author would appear to have taken down his blog, however his website is [here](http://frank-behrens.de).